# How to assign new database to user account(cpanel)?

Tags: phpmyadmin, cpanel, whm

I have root access to phpMyAdmin and i created a database (cpaneluser_databasename) and user using php script, but when I login to the cpanel I cannot find any database there.

Now my question is how to associate a database to a user account by user account I mean cpanel account ? 
Here i find a similar question but i didn't find a proper answer [here](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/assigning-new-database-to-user-account-using-php.198092/).

I am woring on a oneclick installer that will create database and upload files and associate the user account with the database.

Answer (score 0):

select database mysql
insert into user table the correct values
insert into the db table the correct values
flush privileges

for correct values see mysql user manual regarding mysql security
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.0/en/grant-table-structure.html

Answer (score 0):

Insert a new record into a table named 'mysql' and select Yes for all priviledges. According to my experience, you put the MySql user you have created under the user's cpanel in the user field of the record.